# How to populate a multiple select field with this JSON object to be selected and inserted into another object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-model

I have a form that I want to add a multiple select input, but I want the select input to be populated with an existing JSON object and allow me to select one of those objects and add it into the object created by my form.

I have referenced the AngularJS Docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select under "Using select with ngOptions and setting a default value". But the JSON object in the example is a bit different and so is what I am trying to do.

Here is my JSON object that I want loaded into the multiple select input so I can choose which accounts object I want to pick for my form:

```
accounts = [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "DisplayName": "George",
 },
  {
    "Id": 2,
   "DisplayName": "Bob",
  }
]
```

This is the part of the form that has the multiple select input:

```
<div class="form-group">  
    <label for="audience" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Audience:</label>  
    <div class="col-sm-10 space">      
        <select id="audience" ng-model="newAnnouncement.audience" ng-options="accounts.DisplayName for accounts in newAnnouncement.availableAccounts track by accounts.Id" multiple ></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to this input to do is list the DisplayName in order of the Id in the multiple select input dropdown, then when I select them, it adds both the Id and DisplayName from the accounts object to my form input object. I want the JSON object created from this select input to add an object to my form object that looks like this:

```
newAnnouncement = [
  {
    "audience": [
      { "Id":"1",  "DisplayName": "George" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add 'as' into your 'ng-options', like this:

```
 <select id="audience" ng-model="newAnnouncement.audience" ng-options="accountsData as accountsData.DisplayName for accountsData in accounts" multiple ></select>
```

Comment: I just tried adjusting ng-options as you suggested and the select dropdown is still not populated.

Comment: Please write down the piece of code where you try to fetch the data of accounts

Comment: $scope.accounts = [];

my.$onInit = () => {
   $scope.loadAccounts();
};

$scope.loadAccounts = (force) => {
   arcService.getAccounts(successHandler, errorHandler, force);
};

var successHandler = (resp) => {
   $scope.accounts = resp.data;
};

var errorHandler = (resp) => {
   console.error(JSON.stringify(resp));
};

Comment: I can't format that code in a comment. But that is all in my controller for the HTML I posted

Comment: Try this instead of what I wrote to you and also please remove 'track by' for meantime:

<select id="audience" ng-model="newAnnouncement.audience" ng-options="accountsData as accountsData.DisplayName for accountsData in accounts" multiple ></select>

Comment: YOU GOT IT! Thank you very much! Did you use any reference at all? I am still a little new to AngularJS and would like to know if you had a good source I can study.

Comment: Cheers! you're welcome :)
A good reference is a website called 'pluralsight', but for this issue I remembered the solution by heart